# Biggest sum of words of a string in js

Tags: javascript, string, character

I came up to solve this problem in javascript:
Given a string of words, you need to find the highest scoring word.

Each letter of a word scores points according to it's position in the alphabet: a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 etc.

You need to return the highest scoring word as a string.

If two words score the same, return the word that appears earliest in the original string.

### All letters will be lowercase and all inputs will be valid.

my code is the following:

```
    function high(x){
  x = x.split(" ");
  var bestWord = 0;
  var bestWordS = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    var word = x[i].split("");
    var letter;
    var wordScore;
      switch(word[i]){
        case "a":
          letter = 1;
          break;
        case "b":
          letter = 2;
          break;
        case "c":
          letter = 3;
          break;
        case "d":
          letter = 4;
          break;
        case "e":
          letter = 5;
          break;
        case "f":
          letter = 6;
          break;
        case "g":
          letter = 7;
          break;
        case "h":
          letter = 8;
          break;
        case "i":
          letter = 9;
          break;
        case "j":
          letter = 10;
          break;
        case "k":
          letter = 11;
          break;
        case "l":
          letter = 12;
          break;
        case "m":
          letter = 13;
          break;
        case "n":
          letter = 14;
          break;
        case "o":
          letter = 15;
          break;
        case "p":
          letter = 16;
          break;
        case "q":
          letter = 17;
          break;
        case "r":
          letter = 18;
          break;
        case "s":
          letter = 19;
          break;
        case "t":
          letter = 20;
          break;
        case "u":
          letter = 21;
          break;
        case "v":
          letter = 22;
          break;
        case "w":
          letter = 23;
          break;
        case "x":
          letter = 24;
          break;
        case "y":
          letter = 25;
          break;
        case "z":
          letter = 26;
          break;     
      }
      wordScore += letter;
      if ( wordScore > bestWord){
        bestWord = wordScore;
        bestWordS = x[i];
      }
    }
    return bestWordS;

}
```

I don't know what is wrong the function always returns an empty string (  ""   )

Comment: You need to iterate over `word` with a different variable than `i`, since `i` is the index of the word in the sentence.

Comment: Missing a loop to loop over letters in a word also. Your current loop is for each word. Inside that loop over characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the "score" of each word is as in your example, you could simply:
Edit: fixed an issue with the sort function, thanks to @KoshVery

```js
 const scoresByLetter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');
    const sentence = "azzzzim zoom";
    const words = sentence.split(" ");
    
    //Declearing a function to calculate score for a single word
    const calculateWordWeight = (word)=>{
        return Array.prototype.reduce.apply(word, [(score, letter) =>{
            return score + scoresByLetter.indexOf(letter);
        },0]);
    };
    
    //Calculating score for each word
    const scores = words.map(calculateWordWeight);
    
    //Finding the highest score value
    let highestScore = Math.max(scores);

    //Then finding the highest value index
    let highestScoreIndex = scores.indexOf(highestScore);

    //Finally, finding the word by the index
    let wordWithHighestScore = words[highestScoreIndex];
    
    alert(wordWithHighestScore);
```

Comment: @Danikas, Why did you accepted this answer? It's wrong. `let selectedWord = sentence.split(" ").sort().pop();` works wrong here as it sorts words alphabetically, not by score so for string `"azimuth zoom"` it returns `zoom`. Then score for the wrong result is being calculated...

Comment: @KoshVery You are tottaliy correct, I messed up the the function, fixed it and kept it low performance as possible.

Comment: thank you for the update. It makes my previous comment irrelevant, but your updated answer has issues too. Split in `scoresByLetter` is not really needed; you're overusing `apply`; you have unnecessary `returns` and brackets which you could avoid; you're passing `calculateWordWeight` wrapped into an anonimous function to `map` instead of passing `calculateWordWeight` itself; you have two unnecessary loops; your code is not a function as per PO question. All these look poor to me. Sorry if offended.

Answer (score 0):

You might store all your letters in a string and use `indexOf` to get a letter score.
Also you might use one `reduce` to get a word score and another `reduce` to find a word with the greatest score:

```js
const abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

const high = (x) => x.split(/\s+/).reduce((a, w) => (w = [w, [...w].reduce((a, l) => a += 1 + abc.indexOf(l), 0)]) && ~~a[1] > w[1] ? a : w, [])[0]

console.log(high('lorem ipsum dolor'));
```

**Update** for those who have troubles reading oneliners,
a very readable version using two nested `for` loops:

```js
const abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

const high = (x) => {
  let words = x.split(/\s+/);
  let best, maxscore = 0;
  for (let word of words) {
    let score = 0;
    for (let letter of word) {
      score += 1 + abc.indexOf(letter);
    }
    if (score > maxscore) {
      best = word;
      maxscore = score;
    }
  }
  return best;
}

console.log(high('lorem ipsum dolor'));
```

Comment: Just sharing my opinion, one-liners like this are highly not recommended. the code is not readable, and if you pass it through webpack or so, it dose not matter.

Comment: @AdiDarachi, if you use it 10 times a day it becomes easily readable. Anyway, thank you for your opinion.

Comment: @kushVery Make sens, But usually when write code, other developers suppose to read and work with it, you write readable code for them, not for yourself. anyway, in my eyes, when you answer a question in a public website, so developers can later use this answer, the code should be easy and readable, this is the only reason I commented, sorry if offended.

Comment: @AdiDarachi, no problem, there is nothing offensive in your comment. Actually, code like this is really easy and straightforward to me and my team. If a developer cannot read `reduce` expression, I'd suggest spending some time on this topic at MDN and W3Schools.